# I am storing the the modified arraylist in map every iteration, then why map contains only the last modified list?

Tags: java, arrays, debugging, arraylist, hashmap

```java
    import java.util.*;

    import java.lang.*;

    import java.io.*;
                    /*In this question i am modifying the array in every step
                     and adding them to hashmap.
                    But after debugging i found out that hashmap is  
                      containing only the last modified array. */

    class Solution

    {

        public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception

        {
                Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

                int t=sc.nextInt();  /*Testcases*/

                while(t-->0)  /*Iterating t times */

                {
                    /*Size of array*/

                    int n=sc.nextInt();   

                    long k=sc.nextLong(); 

                    /*Creating a hashmap*/

                    Integer arr[]=new Integer[n]; //Initialising the array arr

                    HashMap<Integer,List<Integer>> map=new HashMap<>(); 

                    /*Input array elements*/

                    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
                    {
                       arr[i]=sc.nextInt();
                    }

                    /*Converting array to list*/

                    List<Integer> list=Arrays.asList(arr); 

                    /*Inserting values to hashmap*/

                     map.put(0,list);

                    /*for debugging purpose*/

                     System.out.println(map);

                    /*mid value of array*/

                    int midvalue=arr[(0+(n/2))];



                    /*In this step i am modifying the array in every step
                     and adding them to hashmap.
                    But after debugging i found out that hashmap is  
                      containing only the last modified array. */

                    for(int i=0;i<n*3-1;i++)
                    {
                       /*Performing some operations on array*/

                       int a=arr[(i%n)];

                       int b=arr[(n-(i%n)-1)];

                       int c=a^b;

                       arr[i%n]=c;

                    /*When array is changed,we convert that array to list and store it into map*/

                     List<Integer> k1=Arrays.asList(arr);

                     System.out.println(k1); /*for debugging*/

                     map.put(i+1,k1);  //storing the new modified array to map

                  }

              /*debugging*/

                System.out.println(map);  



         }

    }
}
```

I tried using Collections.addAll method too. Although this method is working but it is giving me TLE in my code. So i dont want to use this method

```
        for(int i=0;i<n*3-1;i++)
        {
             int a=arr[((i%n))];

             int b=arr[(n-(i%n)-1)];

             int c=a^b;

             arr[i%n]=c;

             List<Integer> k1=new ArrayList<>();

                      Collections.addAll(k1,arr);


            map.put(i+1,k1);

        }
```

expected result: {0=[3, 7], 1=[4,7], 2=[4,3], 3=[7, 3], 4=[7, 4], 5=[3, 4]}

actual result: {0=[3, 4], 1=[3, 4], 2=[3, 4], 3=[3, 4], 4=[3, 4], 5=[3, 4]}

Answer (score 0):

try to change your code

```
List<Integer> k1=Arrays.asList(arr);
```

to this.

```
List<Integer> k1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(arr));
```

OR  Like this

```
Integer[] newInteger = arr.clone();

List<Integer> k1 = Arrays.asList(newInteger);
```

why map contains only the last modified list?

Answer to your question.

Because hash map simply adds the reference to hash map, which points to the same list. if you clear one list it will clear all the others, if you update one it will update all the other lists. try to google "pass by reference and pass by value java".

Answer (score -1):

With each iteration of the loop you created a new Integer array, List and Hashmap  objects. Take the creation of objects out of the loop.

Comment: Please explain your answer properly.